# SQL Window Functions - SELECT DISTINCT ORDER BY LIMIT

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, window-functions, postgresql-performance

I have these 3 tables in my PostgreSQL database:

- **artist:** id, name
- **album:** id, title, year, artist_id
- **song:** id, title, album_id

Basically each artist has multiple albums, and each album has multiple songs.

My query correctly returns 25 distinct artist.id's who have a song whose title begins with "The " ordered by the year of the album:

```
SELECT id
FROM (

    -- Remove the duplicate artists
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.id) id, row
    FROM (

        -- Get all matching artists 
        -- This is slow because there is no limit
        SELECT
            artist.id,
            row_number() OVER(ORDER BY album.year DESC) as row
        FROM artist
        LEFT JOIN album ON album.artist_id = artist.id
        LEFT JOIN song ON song.album_id = album.id
        WHERE song.title ilike 'The %'
        ORDER BY album.year DESC

    ) as a

) as b
ORDER BY row
LIMIT 25
```

However it is slow and inefficient because the innermost query has no LIMIT so it will search the entire table for all possible matches.  Ideally it would stop searching when the 25 distinct artist.id's have been found.

Can this query be rewritten or optimized to execute faster?

I think [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tutorial-window.html) could speed things up here, but I haven't been able to figure out something that works.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the plan of the query? Can you show it?

Comment: if you are using filter in the song table u can use inner join in this relation, no?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info and update your post accordingly. Pg version, query plan, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, should work faster than your current query

```
SELECT
  artist.id,                        
  MAX( album.year ) as latest_album_date
FROM 
  artist
  JOIN album ON album.artist_id = artist.id  -- JOIN, not LEFT JOIN
  JOIN song ON song.album_id = album.id      -- Since you have song.title in WHERE clause, it makes no sense to make these as a LEFT JOIN
WHERE 
  song.title ilike 'The %'
GROUP BY
  artist.id
ORDER BY
  latest_album_date DESC
limit 25;
```

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/83b61/22)

Comment: `group by` or `distinct` should be enough. There's no need to use both in this query. Also `group by` will use index to remove duplicates.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, seems obvious now.  32% faster average query time!

Answer (score 2):

```
select id, year
from (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (artist.id) artist.id, album.year
    FROM artist
    inner JOIN album ON album.artist_id = artist.id
    inner JOIN song ON song.album_id = album.id
    WHERE song.title ilike 'The %'
    ORDER BY artist.id, album.year DESC
) s
order by year desc
LIMIT 25
```

An index on `song.title` can help when the ilike expression does start with a `%`

Comment: Another benefit of this answer is that the outer join remains an outer join.  I hadn't noticed before, but, in the original question, since the outer joined table is referred to in the where clause, it effectively becomes an inner join.

Comment: This query will not return `25 distinct artist.id's who have a song whose title begins with "The "`. It will always return first 25 artist id's.

Comment: This needs to be ORDER BY album.year -- not artist.id, hence my nested select statements.  The subquery left join is interesting, I will take a look at that.

Comment: Thank you, this is a major improvement.  27% faster than my query.  But I am accepting @Akash's answer because it is a single SELECT and it is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
Select id, year
from (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (artist.id) artist.id, album.year
    FROM artist
    rightJOIN album ON album.artist_id = artist.id
    left JOIN song ON song.album_id = album.id
    WHERE song.title ilike 'The %'
    ORDER BY artist.id, album.year DESC
) s
order by year desc
LIMIT 25
```